# ARMA & MA methods: how do you know the error terms?

Tags: filtering, moving-average, autoregressive-model

Reading the ARMA model for the first time, and I'm confused.

Let's say I have a time series

```
x = [1, 2.1, 2.9, 3, 4.1]
```

According to the ARMA model, $X_t$ is a linear combination of previous values and errors, something like

$$\sum_i \phi_i X_{t-i} + \sum_i \theta_i \epsilon_{t-i}$$

But, what are $X_i$ and $\epsilon_i$??

- is $X_i$ the actual value of the series at $t=i$? Eg, in my example $X_2 = 2.1 ?? (with 1-based indexing)
- if so, what are the error terms?

The same question for the simple moving-average model, where all the $X_i$ values are remain unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of discrete-time statistical signal processing, an ARMA-(p,q) random process is defined as (assuming zero initial conditions)

$$ \sum_{k=0}^p a_k ~ x[n-k]  = \sum_{k=0}^q b_k ~ v[n-k] $$

or equivalently

$$ x[n] = - \sum_{i=1}^p a_i ~ x[n-i]  + \sum_{i=0}^q b_i ~ v[n-i] $$

where $v[n]$ is a white-noise (WSS) random process with variance $\sigma_v^2$ and $x[n]$ represents the resulting ARMA process.

In this context your coefficients are related as $$\phi_i = - a_i $$ and $$\theta_i = b_i$$ The process reggresses over its past values $x[n-i]$ ($X_{t-i}$ acc) and is also a moving average of the input noise $v[n-i]$ ($\epsilon_{t-i}$ acc).

Comment: That was a nice way of representing the ARMA in a DSP framework. One thing I don't get. Is it possible to define the impulse response of an ARMA since the model has both noise terms and it's own lagged terms ? It doesn't seem possible to me. Any comments or references are appreciated because the time-series literature, AFAIK, doesn't discuss the impulse response much. Thanks.

Comment: @Fat32: still, my question is, where do the values of the noise come from? Do I randomly generate them during regression, instead of getting them from external source? And, if so, what is the point?

Comment: Now, the **error** you mention is the **white-noise** sequence here. First the white-noise of sufficeint length is generated then it's filtered by $x = filter(b,a,w)$ to get the ARMA-process. In this perspective, ARMA is used to **gererate** x from w. But in another perspective it can be used to **model** x[n] up to error terms w[n]. So it depends on how you view the process. yes @markleeds once the ARMA coefficients $a$ and $b$ are defined, the following Matlab/Octave command *h = impz(b,a,M)* produces the impulse response truncated to the length M.

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks. That's useful if I ever use Matlab but I'm interested in the theoretical DSP derivation. I'll google for "impulse response and ARIMA models" and see if anything useful comes up. If so, I'll post any good links.

Comment: @blue_note: IMHO, you're asking a very good question about the error term. From a DSP viewpoint, I don't know how it's viewed. But I have a very good article titled "the history of the error term in econometrics." that gives a nice explanation of it's history.  I can't find it on the internet so, if you want it, email me. It's my name with a 2 on the end and the other part is that famous mail system that starts with a g. anyone else who wants it is welcome to email me also. I don't want to over-hype the article but it is somewhat of an odd concept, atleast to me. .

Comment: @Fat32: I did find this which shows how to do it for the ARMA(1,1) so I imagine the same approach can be used for any ARMA model. Then, once you have the function as they show in the link, one can just interpret it the same way as in DSP. I was thinking that it wasn't possible since new $\epsilon$ are constantly arriving but it seems that they are assumed zero just as in DSP. Thanks for making me look. I knew it was possible for AR's and MA's but not ARMA's.  Now I see how they do it and interpretation is same as DSP.  https://math.unice.fr/~frapetti/CorsoP/chapitre_23_IMEA_1.pdf

Comment: @markleeds the error term is not zero. It's the white noise. For every $n$ there is a new noise sample $w[n]$...Those samples can be generated at run time one by one but also offline is possible. Those matlab functions are implementing the LCCDE that I have written above to  describe ARMA-(p,q). The impulse response of that LCCDE is found by setting $w[n] = \delta[n]$ in which case noise is zero of course...

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks.  I will read and ponder carefully because, in econometrics, we estimate the $b_{i}$ and $a_{i}$ so the $v_{i]$ sequence is not generated but rather part of the actual series. Based on what you're saying, I think the DSP error term viewpoint is very different from the econometric one. I'm gonna read the link I attached to also because it's been a while. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds let me once more restate: 1- if you want to produce an ARMA-(p,q) process $x[n]$ then you first generate a white-noise $w[n]$ and filter it through an LTI system H(z) with coeff are $a$,$b$ the output will be $x[n]$. 2- Given a random process $x[n]$ you want to model it as an ARMA and find those coef $a$,$b$ then the error (white noise) will be generated as a result. (indeed this will be the inverse filtering with 1/H(z) of the first case). So they are the same thing looked from opposite ends.

Comment: @Fat32:  Apologies for my dense-ness. Will ponder carefully but one last bother: What would H(z) be in the ARMA(1,1) case say. I'm better with an actual example especially in DSP world. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds $$\boxed{ H(z) = \frac{ b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} } {1 + a_1 z^{-1}  }  }$$ and the LCCDE : $$\boxed{ x[n] + a_1 x[n-1] = b_0 w[n] + b_1 w[n-1]  }$$ Statistical Digital Signal Processing_Monson HAYES_chapters 3 & 4. present a verry good introduction to DSP mood of ARMA processes.

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks so  much. That clarifies for sure.  And I will make that text the next book I invest in. Finally,  not that it matters much, but it's ARMA(1,1), so $b_{0} = 1$ in your useful example.

Comment: @markleeds In DSP context, $b_0$ is not necessarily $1$, unlike $a_0$ which is assumed to be $1$ (almost) always. It's data dependent. So there are $q+1$ unknown $b$ coefficients but only $p$ unknown $a$ coefficients as $a_0 = 1$.

Comment: Okay. Then that's a difference between (econometrics-statistical time-series) and (DSP). In the former, we don't estimate a coefficient on $w[n]$ because it's contemporaneous with the new $x[n]$ so viewed as noise that comes in as part of the response. If this makes no sense, then just take it as a key difference between the two fields. In the non-dsp world, there are also 3 parameters in the ARMA(1,1) but two are coefficients and the other is  $\sigma^2_{w}$. . I ordered  Monson Hayes text so it will be neat to go through that. Thanks for recommendation. It also had good reviews on Amazon.

Comment: @markleeds ok. HAYES also has a Schaum's outlines of DSP series that I highly recommend. It's really really helpful to solve examples there to develop the must have skills for DSP. Also when you feel ready then find a copy of Charles Therrien's statistical signal processing book as probably the zenith of dsp+stat (theoretical) book. Steven Kay's books are also top notch dsp+stat style.  Now I have a question to you. What's the difference between a *statistical estimation algorithm* and a *probabilistic estimation algorithm* ?

Comment: Thx. I'll definitely obtain them slowly.. As far as the terms, I'm pretty familiar with statistical estimation algorithms. probabilistic estimation algorithms not as much but it may be refereeing to monte carlo markov chain type estimation algs such as gibbs sampling or metropolis hastings. Not sure if that term is standard but, if there is a difference, then that maybe what that means. If you want refs on gibbs sampling or metropolis hastings, let me know. I worked on that that in another life so  tons of texts but I can't recall which  were good but I can look. thx for great suggestions..

Comment: one other thing: do they estimate $\sigma^2_{w}$ in dsp arma world. I ask because it would be quite difficult to estimate it if $b_{0}$ doesn't equal 1.0. But maybe it's not so important in DSP world. It's very important in econometric-time series world.

Comment: I found this which would mean I was wrong earlier but the term might be so general that it could refer to different concepts depending on who uses it. https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1474667017354563/1-s2.0-S1474667017354563-main.pdf?_tid=193bc7d3-90cd-4681-9d31-c935efb6c4e0&acdnat=1539749796_b7362e48223ba03ea3bb8dc316dd3c76

Comment: @markleeds sorry for teh confusion. The *estimation* eas not teh focus but teh difference between *statistical* vs *probabilistic* was the concern. For example cosnider a RV X and its mean $ E\{X\} = \int x f_X(x) dx $ is this a statistical definition of the mean? or the sample mean $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_k x_k$ is this statistical or probabilistic (estimator)? I'm looking for a clear distinction between the terms *statistical* and *probabilistic*...

Comment: @markleeds noise power can be estimated or assumed depending on the context.

Comment: @Fat32: No problem. In my experience, that's DEFINITELY statistical. Yes, there's a probability density involved but any time there is a statistic being estimated, it's statistical. probabilistic I think is more algorithmic such as running simulations-genrating RV's, etc. Just my opinion-experience but I think it's correct.

Comment: @Fat32: it just arrived and I only glanced at it for a half hour or so but Monson Hayes' text is the best book I've seen as far as providing a clear "dsp in time series" viewpoint. It's quite enlightening to see that viewpoint presented in a clear way. Thanks. P.S: To any new DSPers: I don't have Kay which is supposed to be good also. See thread above for links.

Comment: @markleeds I'm glad you found Hayes' book useful. That book deserves more credits for practical DSP engineers' attention.